# Is it possible to install vineyard to Ubuntu Trial?

Tags: command-line, wine

I follow the steps on this site http://sourcedigit.com/19248-wine-setup-on-ubuntu-install-vineyard-to-configure-wine-on-ubuntu/

Terminal message appeared:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install vineyard
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vineyard : Depends: wine
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is it because I have not yet installed the Ubuntu? I'm just trying it out first.

Answer (score 0):

The try Ubuntu setting will not have all the packages installed and certain programs and features will not work. You will want to go ahead and install ubuntu, you could install it to a flash drive if you do not want to install it right away on you pc.

Answer (score 0):

It is posible.

However, since Live sessions doesn't have all the packages installed or the sources activated, you may need to activate the software sources first:

- Open the HUD and look for the Software and Updates app, activate *Main* and *Universe* repositories in the first tab and close the window.

Or add the specific third party repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds && sudo apt-get update
```

After that it should be possible to install vineyard.

Also, remember that anything you do in a live session will be lost once you restart your PC, unless you manually save it somewhere else.